# How to return custom response when FluentValidation returns an error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, fluentvalidation

I'm using `FluentValidation` to validate inputs for my `ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API`. I'm doing it with the "automatic" way. So in my `Startup` class I have this:

```
        services.AddControllers()
            .AddFluentValidation(opt =>
            {
                opt.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining(typeof(UserInputValidator));
            });
```

This way, `FluentValidation` magically validates all inputs from the above assembly, with no  other code needed. Pretty sweet, but... the response format, is different than response format I use when I return `BadRequest`. This is FluentValidation format:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|3b037c98-40d28ab8553d6989.",
    "errors": {
        "UserId": [
            "'User Id' must be greater than '0'."
        ],
        "Score": [
            "'Score' must be between 0 and 500. You entered 900."
        ]
    }
}
```

I would rather have:

```
{
    "code": 123456,
    "message": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "errors": [
        "'User Id' must be greater than '0'.",
        "'Score' must be between 0 and 500. You entered 900."
    ]
}
```

So my question is, Is it possible to override it?

I have one idea, but not sure if it's a good practice (or even possible), but if `FluentValidation` instead of returning its `BadRequest response` would throw an exception, I would be able to catch it in the middleware and reformat.

In any event, `FluentValidation` is very popular, `.NET Core WebAPI` is very popular. It's hard for me to believe that "ninja developers" would just use response provided by thrid-party tool, that doesn't match their response format. Yet, I don't see many materials how to fix it (even on the `FluentValidation` website. Did I miss it?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758024/use-custom-validation-responses-with-fluent-validation)

Comment: @MuhammadHannan The problem with these answers, is that they don't solve the issue with error codes

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve this result by using Filters in asp.net core. After you have completed setting up Fluent Validation you have to write a filter.

```
 public class CustomValidationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var errors = context.ModelState.Values.Where(v => v.Errors.Count > 0)
                        .SelectMany(v => v.Errors)
                        .Select(v => v.ErrorMessage)
                        .ToList();

                var responseObj = new
                {                        
                    Code= 123456,
                    Message = "One or more validation errors occurred.",
                    Errors = errors
                };

                context.Result = new JsonResult(responseObj)
                {
                    StatusCode = 200
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

And in the startup class define this filter.

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(typeof(CustomValidationAttribute));
            })
            .AddFluentValidation(fvc => fvc.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<AnyValidatorClass>());

            services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
            });
```

Comment: I want to custom error message when validation error . is this possible?

Comment: I want to return custom message when consist of error. Is This possible? @Muhammad Umer Naeem