# How Can I throw exceptions using FluentValidation .net 6?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

I migrated my web api from asp net core 3.1 to .net 6 and I'm having some issues with the using FluentValidation library.

```
RuleFor(x => x.Name)
            .NotEmpty()
            .OnFailure(x =>
            {
                var message = "El nombre del Usuario es requerido.";
                throw new HttpException(message, message, (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            })
            .Length(1, 150)
            .OnFailure(x =>
            {
                var message = "El nombre del Usuario debe contener hasta máximo 150 caracteres.";
                throw new HttpException(message, message, (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            });
```

This code used to work correctly but, when I updated the library , the method .OnFailure() is deprecated.

I would like to know how can I throw a custom exception for each OnFailure as I used to do it, where HttpException is a custom class that inherited from Exception. An example  of json result would be:

```
    {
  "developerMessage": "El nombre del Usuario es requerido..",
  "userMessage": "El nombre del Usuario es requerido.",
  "errorCode": 400,
  "moreInfo": ""
   }
```

**UPDATED**!

I followed this article https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-use-of-fluent-validation-in-chash-and-how-to-use-in-chash. I used CascadeMode.Stop because the previous one is deprecated but, when I  try testing .Lenght validation, the result variable shows the firt error of each RuleFor(). I mean: If I have 3 RuleFor() and each rule has 2 validators, the result variable shows the first error message's validator of each RuleFor() and no error message of the real failure.

How can I solve this?

```
public UserValidator()
{
  RuleFor(x => x.Name)
                .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("El nombre del Usuario es requerido.")
                .Length(1, 150).WithMessage("El nombre del Usuario debe contener hasta máximo 150 caracteres.");

  var result = Validate(new User()); //I need to get the context (user) to validate it , **not new User()**
        if(!result.IsValid)
        {
            foreach(var error in result.Errors)
            {
                var message = $"{error.ErrorMessage}";
                throw new HttpException(message, message, (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using `WithMessage()` instead of `OnFailure()` and then throwing the exception if model state is invalid in a [custom action filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69582675/8065832)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ValidateAndThrow` method of your validation class that comes by inheriting from the `AbstractValidator<T>` class.

In your case, as you want to throw the `HttpException` exception, you must override the `RaiseValidationException` method of your validation classes so that they can throw the desired exception.

There are two ways to do this:

1 - Overriding the `RaiseValidationException` method for each validation class:

```
public class UserValidator : AbstractValidator<User>
{
    public UserValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name)
            .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("El nombre del Usuario es requerido.")
            .Length(1, 150)
            .WithMessage("El nombre del Usuario debe contener hasta máximo 150 caracteres.");
    }

    // Add this override on your validation class
    protected override void RaiseValidationException(ValidationContext<User> context, ValidationResult result)
    {
        var firstError = result.Errors[0];

        var ex = new HttpExcpetion(firstError.ErrorMessage, (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        throw ex;
    }
}
```

2 - Creating an abstract class with the method overriding so that there is no need to re-implement each validation class:

```
public abstract class CustomAbstractValidator<T> : AbstractValidator<T>
{
    protected override void RaiseValidationException(ValidationContext<T> context, ValidationResult result)
    {
        var firstError = result.Errors[0];

        var ex = new HttpExcpetion(firstError.ErrorMessage, (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        throw ex;
    }
}

public class UserValidator : CustomAbstractValidator<User>
{
    public UserValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name)
            .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("El nombre del Usuario es requerido.")
            .Length(1, 150)
            .WithMessage("El nombre del Usuario debe contener hasta máximo 150 caracteres.");
    }
}
```

After implementing it, just get your validator instance and call the `ValidateAndThrow` method:

1 - Without dependency injection:

```
public class YourProgramFlowClass
{
    public void YourMethod()
    {
        // ... before validation code

        var validator = new UserValidator();

        validator.ValidateAndThrow(user);

        // ... after validation code
    }
}
```

2 - Without dependency injection:

```
public class YourProgramFlowClass
{
    private readonly IValidator<ClassToValidate> _validator;

    public YourProgramFlowClass(IValidator<ClassToValidate> validator)
    {
        _validator = validator;
    }

    public void YourMethod()
    {
        // ... before validation code

        _validator.ValidateAndThrow(user);

        // ... after validation code
    }
}
```