# how to remove "type", "title", "traceId": from FluentValidation response in .net core 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, fluentvalidation, asp.net-core-6.0

I am using FluentValidation to validate my api request model.

I want to remove "type","title","traceId" from  FluentValidation response.

How I can do this in .net core 6 ?

FluentValidation response:

```
{
"type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1", 
"title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
"status": 400,
"traceId": "00-8c3b4249b59b316dc6f50d49851844ef-5e09e9b0133b949b-00",
"errors": {
  "Amount": ["'Amount' must not be empty."]
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return custom response when FluentValidation returns an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64013050/how-to-return-custom-response-when-fluentvalidation-returns-an-error)

Comment: Also see [Use custom validation responses with fluent validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758024/use-custom-validation-responses-with-fluent-validation)

Comment: @gunr2171 almost same. those errors come in array but I want it like FluentValidation give as  "errors": { "Amount":["'Amount' must not be empty." , "value-2",so on], ..........}